# How to install the qmlscene module version need?

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm trying to run a QML without the Ubuntu SDK in Ubuntu 14.04.

```
costales@desktop:~/Desktop$ qmlscene qml/Main.qml 
file:///home/costales/Desktop/unav_jkb/qml/Main.qml:16 module "QtQuick" version 2.4 is not installed
costales@desktop:~/Desktop$
```

How can I install that exactly QtQuick version module into Trusty (without install the Ubuntu SDK)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For a quick test, you could post your Main.qml

Comment: @A.B. http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12082052/ This is a basic example. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Qt versions can be installed.

Download a binary installer from the Qt site. Then use `qmlscene` from the needed version. Latest Qt 5.x version should work with that QtQuick version.